# Drawing a barchart to compare two sets of data using ggplot2 package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

What is the best way to construct a barplot to compare two sets of data?

e.g. dataset:

```
Number <- c(1,2,3,4)
Yresult <- c(1233,223,2223,4455)
Xresult <- c(1223,334,4421,0)
nyx <- data.frame(Number, Yresult, Xresult)
```

What I want is Number across X and bars beside each other representing the individual X and Y values

Comment: There are so many questions like this one - standard procedure: melt (from reshape2) dataframe to long format, then you can set aes(x=number,y=value,fill=variable) where variable will indicate yresult or xresult

Comment: Well, read the documentation or look at one of the tutorials. However, some people consider "publication quality figures" and barplots to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: There is [an online reference for the ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/index.html) package. Also a very good resource is the book *R Graphics Cookbook* from *Winston Chang*.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to your question. `ggplot` is brilliant. The documentation, not so much. It's really confusing if you're new to it. Try [this link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/).

Comment: BTW: see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) for recommendations on how to pose a question that is more likely to get responses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is better to reshape your data into long format. You can do that with for example the `melt` function of the *reshape2* package (alternatives are `reshape` from base R, `melt` from *data.table* (which is an extended implementation of the `melt` function of *reshape2*) and `gather` from *tidyr*).

Using your dataset:

```
# load needed libraries
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# reshape your data into long format
nyxlong <- melt(nyx, id=c("Number"))

# make the plot
ggplot(nyxlong) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Number, y = value, fill = variable), 
           stat="identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual("Result\n", values = c("red","blue"), 
                    labels = c(" Yresult", " Xresult")) +
  labs(x="\nNumber",y="Result\n") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)
```

which gives the following barchart:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This has provided me with the initial start to ggplot2 that I was looking for. Very much appreciated.